# Ajax using JQuery in ASP .NET c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to use JQuery ajax in asp .net c#. The code I am using is ...

HTML FORM:

```
<div>
    Your Name :
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time"
     onclick = "ShowCurrentTime()" />
</div>
```

JQuery Part :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowCurrentTime() {
        //alert(window.location.pathname);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Display.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
            data: '{name: "' + $("#< %=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}
function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response.d);
}
</script>
```

CS PArt:

```
    using System.Web.Services;

    This part below is under partial class which inherits from Page class.

   [WebMethod]

    public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
    {

     return "Hello "+ name +"! " + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
            + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

Problem:
       It is not working. Please let me know if I am missing any setting or any name space. Or any thing. URL I Put in ajax Call is correct as I verified it by 
var pathname = window.location.pathname;  I supplied data also while calling ajax.

Comment: Do you have jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js

Comment: Does anything go out back to the server. Load the tool Fiddler to ensure you can see a request going out. Narrow it down to client or server so we can help troubleshoot.

Comment: what does not work ? could we see your console ?

Comment: @Stralos I can see the console. There is no call from any where.

Comment: @HerGiz  I think jQuery.unobstrustive-ajax.min.js is not required for this call.

Comment: What is the status code and error you receive with this as you click on the button? Also, as far as I know, ajax doesn't understand "failure", but "error".

Comment: 'GetCurrentTime' .. is it located inside the code behind ? Your questions points to cs file, not sure if by that you mean aspx.cs

Comment: @DinoMyte   YES IT IS IN CODE BEHIND.

Comment: @tedcurrent    Unfortunately I am not getting any error. :(

Comment: @EnigmaticMind ah, then it is very likely you have to swap out "failure" to "error"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe changing

```
 failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
```

to

```
 error: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
```

Will help find the issue.
I don't see a failure callback in the docs - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thank you. After changing failure to error it started working. :)

Answer (score 2):

The things I can see right off the bat:

1. $.ajax doesn't take a "failure" parameter, but rather "error."  Even
   then, you should be using .done() and .fail() instead (see
   http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
2. Your error handling function will be triggered when your page method
       throws an exception.  The first parameter is a jqXHR object, not a
       JSON response from .NET (see the same link as from #1).
3. Your page method should not go UNDER the page class, but within it.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has some error

```
    $("#< %=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value
```

need to be

```
    $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value
```

or

```
    $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>").val()
```

Comment: Thanks. But the space here is by mistake. In my program it is the same as what you have suggested.